# How to count accumulative unique values by groups in python?

Tags: python, pandas, unique, group

I wonder how to count accumulative unique values by groups in python?

Below is the dataframe example:

| Group | Year | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1998 | red |
| A | 1998 | blue |
| A | 2002 | red |
| A | 2005 | blue |
| A | 2008 | blue |
| A | 2008 | yello |
| B | 1998 | red |
| B | 2001 | red |
| B | 2003 | red |
| C | 1996 | red |
| C | 2002 | orange |
| C | 2002 | red |
| C | 2012 | blue |
| C | 2012 | yello |

I need to create a new column by Column "Group". The value of this new column should be the accumulative unique values of Column "Type", accumulating by Column "Year".

Below is the dataframe I want.
For example:
(1)For Group A and in year 1998, I want to count the unique value of Type in year 1998, and there are two unique values of Type: red and blue.
(2)For Group A and in year 2002, I want to count the unique value of Type in year 1998 and 2002, and there are also two unique values of Type: red and blue.
(3)For Group A and in year 2008, I want to count the unique value of Type in year 1998, 2002, 2005, and 2008, and there are also four unique values of Type: red, blue, and yellow.

| Group | Year | Type | Want |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1998 | red | 2 |
| A | 1998 | blue | 2 |
| A | 2002 | red | 2 |
| A | 2005 | blue | 2 |
| A | 2008 | blue | 3 |
| A | 2008 | yello | 3 |
| B | 1998 | red | 1 |
| B | 2001 | red | 1 |
| B | 2003 | red | 1 |
| C | 1996 | red | 1 |
| C | 2002 | orange | 2 |
| C | 2002 | red | 2 |
| C | 2012 | blue | 4 |
| C | 2012 | yello | 4 |

One more thing about this dataframe: not all groups have values in the same years. For example, group A has two values in year 1998 and 2008, one value in year 2002 and 2005. Group B has values in year 1998, 2001, and 2003.

I wonder how to address this problem. Your great help means a lot to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use custom lambda function with [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
f = lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]
df['Want1'] = df.groupby('Group', sort=False)['Type'].transform(f) + 1
print (df)
   Group  Year    Type  Want1
0      A  1998     red      1
1      A  2002     red      1
2      A  2005    blue      2
3      A  2008    blue      2
4      A  2009   yello      3
5      B  1998     red      1
6      B  2001     red      1
7      B  2003     red      1
8      C  1996     red      1
9      C  2002  orange      2
10     C  2008    blue      3
11     C  2012   yello      4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help! I've revised my question. Would you please take a look at it again and see how it works?

Comment: I want to the unique number of "Type" by "Group", accumulating by "year". Would you please help me with it?

Comment: @leilei - Not understand ouput, why is `2` in second and third ouput rows?

Comment: @leilei - `For group A and in Year 1998, the accumulative unique values of "Type" is 2.` Why for group `A` not exist `1` in column `Want`? Why first value is `2`?

Comment: (1)For Group A and in year 1998, I want to count the unique value of Type in year 1998, and there are two unique values of Type: red and blue. (2)For Group A and in year 2002, I want to count the unique value of Type in year 1998 and 2002, and there are also two unique values of Type: red and blue.  (3)For Group A and in year 2008,  I want to count the unique value of Type in year 1998, 2002, 2005, and 2008, and there are also four unique values of Type: red, blue, and yellow.

Comment: I want to accumulate unique values.